# Issue with CSS for mat-input and mat-form-field

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I tried doing a stackblitz but it doesn't accept my `<mat-form-field>` and `<mat-label>` tags without errors, I imported the needed components but it won't work.

But maybe you can help me anyway if I post here the code, I'm having an issue with CSS as I don't know what to target to move the `<mat-label>` tag, when I use a `<mat-form-field>` with `appearance="outline"` when the label is in the center, over the `input field`, I can't move it, I want it to be centered, but it's at the bottom of the `mat-form-field`.

If I adjust the `position:absolute` values, the problem is, that also when the label goes above the field when a click happens, those rules will be applied as well, moving the floating label in the wrong position.

The code:

```
<div 
    id="test" 
    fxLayout="row" 
    fxLayoutGap="12px" 
    fxLayoutAlign="start center" 
    [class.hasFocus]="numberMatInput.value">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
         <mat-label>KM</mat-label>
         <input matInput #numberMatInput [formControl]="numberInput">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#test ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline {
  width: 65px;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 1.725;
}

#test ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#test ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-infix {
  padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
}
```

this is the wanted result :

[image]

so basically I need to move the label when the input field is untouched, and leave it in the same space floating above when it's focused.

to me it seems there is only one rule for both, so if I move the untouched label, the floating one will move as well.

Can someone help? thank you

Comment: The class `.mat-form-field-appearance-outline` doesn't seem to exist?

Comment: it exists, it s what gives the with and the height of the mat-form-field, these classes are directly from the chrome dev tool and they work in my css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the following css:

```
#test ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-hide-placeholder .mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
   text-align: center;
   top: -25px;
}

#test ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-should-float {
   text-align: center;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-l74chd)

Comment: Good job @kboul thnks anyway

Comment: Thank you @harkeshkumar. Did you face also this issue?

Comment: thank you very much! I literally found a solution 1 min before you posted, but yours seems much cleaner! I abused !important and targeted the 3 instances (label inside, label above, and label above with input not empty)

as I did a change and instead to have the floating label in the center but in the left corner, could you help me apply your solution to the current styling?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-2qmksf

Comment: Just replace your css with mine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-gbkb4f. You can check also the demo I included in the answer.

Comment: I added a rule to your stackblitz, to make the floating label white space be on the left instead of the center, but now I can't move in the same place the floating label, could you check it out please?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-szexuh

Comment: It you have the html on the center the floating effect shouldn't be on the center as well? It is just a matter of personal preference but it looks nice on the center.

Comment: I think I prefer it on the side the label! if it's not too much complicated to push the floating label on the side, otherwise it's good like this, thank you very much for the help anyway!

Comment: No problem, consider up voting or accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: I kept hearing and reading some comments saying, ::ng-deep will be deprecated - not sure how this will affect this answer.